# Return only records validated against a lookup table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL and have a little issue I'm struggling to find a fix for. I'm able to achieve this programatically via PHP using a few queries, but I'm sure I can do it as a single query :)

I have 3 tables:

1. products
2. product_keywords
3. valid_keywords

Each product has a number of keywords, these are referenced by a keyword_id in the "product_keywords" table. The "valid_keywords" table contains only the keywords that are allowed (i.e. as the look-up table). I need to return ONLY the products that have the keywords that match those in the "valid_keywords" table.

The valid products must not have any keywords that are not in the "valid_keywords" table.

Here are some test tables/records:

**-- Table structure for table products**

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `prod_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prod_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY `prod_id` (`prod_id`)
);
```

**-- Data for table products**

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`prod_id`, `prod_name`) VALUES(1, 'Prod 1');
INSERT INTO `products` (`prod_id`, `prod_name`) VALUES(2, 'Prod 2');
INSERT INTO `products` (`prod_id`, `prod_name`) VALUES(3, 'Prod 3');
INSERT INTO `products` (`prod_id`, `prod_name`) VALUES(4, 'Prod 4');
```

**-- Table structure for table product_keywords**

```
CREATE TABLE `product_keywords` (
  `prod_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `prod_id` (`prod_id`),
  KEY `keyword_id` (`keyword_id`)
);
```

**-- Data for table product_keywords**

```
INSERT INTO `product_keywords` (`prod_id`, `keyword_id`) VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO `product_keywords` (`prod_id`, `keyword_id`) VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO `product_keywords` (`prod_id`, `keyword_id`) VALUES(2, 2);
INSERT INTO `product_keywords` (`prod_id`, `keyword_id`) VALUES(2, 4);
INSERT INTO `product_keywords` (`prod_id`, `keyword_id`) VALUES(3, 4);
INSERT INTO `product_keywords` (`prod_id`, `keyword_id`) VALUES(3, 6);
INSERT INTO `product_keywords` (`prod_id`, `keyword_id`) VALUES(4, 7);
INSERT INTO `product_keywords` (`prod_id`, `keyword_id`) VALUES(4, 8);
```

**-- Table structure for table valid_keywords**

```
CREATE TABLE `valid_keywords` (
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY `keyword_id` (`keyword_id`)
);
```

**-- Data for table valid_keywords**

```
INSERT INTO `valid_keywords` (`keyword_id`, `keyword_name`) VALUES(2, 'Keyword 2');
INSERT INTO `valid_keywords` (`keyword_id`, `keyword_name`) VALUES(4, 'Keyword 4');
INSERT INTO `valid_keywords` (`keyword_id`, `keyword_name`) VALUES(7, 'Keyword 7');
INSERT INTO `valid_keywords` (`keyword_id`, `keyword_name`) VALUES(8, 'Keyword 8');
```

For the example data, the query should return products 2 & 4.

Hope you guys can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT p.prod_id FROM products p
  LEFT JOIN product_keywords pk
    ON p.prod_id = pk.prod_id
  LEFT JOIN valid_keywords vk
    ON vk.keyword_id = pk.keyword_id
GROUP BY p.prod_id
  HAVING COUNT(vk.keyword_id) = COUNT(pk.keyword_id);

+---------+
| prod_id |
+---------+
|       2 |
|       4 |
+---------+
```

Comment: I knew there would be a "HAVING" clause in there! I'll play with this and feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Get the products that does not have a keyword that is not valid.

```
SELECT prod_id,
       prod_name
FROM   products
WHERE  prod_id NOT IN (SELECT prod_id
                       FROM   product_keywords
                       WHERE  keyword_id NOT IN (SELECT keyword_id
                                                 FROM   valid_keywords));
```

Comment: This is also valid. Will need to determine the performance of between the two, but personally I like the JOIN/HAVING option. Thanks for your time and help